# WMWARE and windows 7 network problem

Tags: vmware-player

Sorry I have not idea about windows, not really interested (I always use Linux) but at my work gotta use it now, so it's the rule.

My problem is with Wmware and a network issue, let me explain you:

1. Scenario:

A) I gotta a laptop with windows 7 here are my network configuration (the IP is fixed):

ip: 192.168.1.236
netmask: 255.255.255.0
default gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS:192.168.1.113

B) I have the wmware player network adaptor defined, maybe that's wrong?:

I just configured ip and subnet mask:

ip:192.168.1.1
netmask: 255.255.255.0

C) I have a debian installed under the Vmware and I settup the network with another fix ip it's been assigned to me to by the network admin:

ip: 192.168.1.238
netmask: 255.255.255.0
default gateway: 192.168.1.1
DNS:192.168.1.113
broadcast: 192.168.1.255

2. What I'm triying is:

A) to have the debian virtual machine with access to the internet
B) I want that virtual machine visible into the network to the others as if it was another common server

3. My problem:

A) When I settup the VMware with NAT my virtual server can be seen  in the network with the assigned ip but can't reach the internet

B) when I settup the Wmware virtual machine in bridge or host only I can reach the internet from the virtual machine but can't be seen on my network by another computer

I'm sure that I am doing something super wrong, probabilly I'm network idiot, but.... no idea.

Could you help me please?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

You assigned an IP conflict to that vmware adapter, its going to think that 1.1 is local to your own machine. change that information or take it out entirely, you DEFINITELY want to be using bridged mode here.

Comment: further explanation: you need to change the vmware player network adapter's configuration to be an IP subnet that is NOT ending in 1.X, let's say 2.X, this would fix things in NAT'd configuration, but also when in bridged modem it won't try and send traffic down that virtual adapter since the link local connection would be a 2.X address.

Comment: so I have to remove the gateway from the linux configuration???

Comment: I changed the vmware network adaptor ip to 192.168.2.1, should I changes something in the linux virtual server? I'm using bridge now

Comment: Nothing else should be changed, it should work now.

Comment: not working, I don't now...

Comment: I see there's two adaptors created by vmware in windows 7, why?

Comment: It's hard to explain since you don't seem to get some fundamentals here. Basically the adapters created by VMware are used when you need to route or use NAT packets to a VM. Because the host is now playing router it needs interfaces into those networks and the virtual switch connects the VM to the adapter. In BRIDGED mode, these are not used, and the physical NIC should be selected as the adapter to pass on to the VM.

Comment: http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_changing_bridged_windows.html

Comment: so if i use the bridge mode I don't even need to use the adapters? what else apart of the virtual server conf network should i setup? sorry, no idea

Comment: that's it, you're done, the virtual adapters are for using the host a router for guest VM's, just configure the VM's networking, set it to bridge mode, and make sure it's using the right NIC on your host.